# Programmatically create a organic group

Tags: 6, organic-groups

How would you programmatically create an OG group? I have tried [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save) but to no joy.

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: 6. Tag added to question.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the [og_nodeapi](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--og--og.module/function/og_nodeapi/6) function, it looks like node_save should do the trick. I can't see why it doesn't work. Just a thought: maybe you can try building a $form_state array and run [drupal_execute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6).

Answer (score 5):

It's simpler than attaching node as group post:

```
  <?php
  global $user;
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'group'; // Change this to group node type name.
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->title = t('Title'); // Change title generation
  $node->body = t('Body'); // Change body generation
  $node->og_description = t('Group description'); // Change group description generation
  $node->og_selective = OG_CLOSED;
  $node->og_register = OG_REGISTRATION_NEVER;
  $node->og_directory = OG_DIRECTORY_CHOOSE_FALSE;
  $node->og_private = 0;
  node_save($node);
  og_insert_group($node);
  og_save_subscription($node->nid, $node->uid, array('is_active' => 1, 'is_admin' => 1));
```

(ofcourse you also need to check the return values from alle the three functions)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question, but I created a lot of groups using the [Mass Create](http://drupal.org/project/mass_create) module.

Comment: well laxman13 and Reg Gordon - thx for the answer. I try to do it like you. I come back and report all my findings!

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same struggle, but I realized that to create a new OG group programatically, the Rules module could be the key.

If you look for the right trigger and conditions, the first action would be "Entities > Create a new entity >OG group.

You can use the Rules scheduler to do the timing, if necessary.